# Rails superclass mismatch for class on migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am junior Ruby on Rails dev.

I have this problem: I've updated my rails from 5.1 to 6. If I try to run

```
rails db:migrate
```

there are errors:

> TypeError: superclass mismatch for class CreateVacancyFields

Looking inside my migration file:

```
class CreateVacancyFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[ 5.1 ]
```

Ok, I've changed 5.1 to 6.0 like this:

```
class CreateVacancyFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[ 6.0 ]
```

But it doesn't help. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly you're having the same named class `CreateVacancyFields` twice. If so, rename it to some different name to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking into this, you must probably have made a previous migration with the same name, if you haven't used it will look empty

```
`class NameOfModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
end`
```

just delete the file from db folder, just make sure it is not active then `rails db:migrate`